# biblatex: List of references of own papers in appendix (might intersect with bibliography)

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

In my thesis I need a `chapter` in the appendix, which lists my own papers.

How can I achieve that with the following conditions:

- `biblatex` is used
- it is possible that a paper has already been cited in the text and therefore is in the main bibliography -> it then shall *also* appear in the appendix
- most of those papers of my own have *not* been cited in the text and therefore shall *not* appear in the main bibliography!
- the papers for the appendix are marked with the keyword "myPapers"
- the bibliography in the appendix shall have no heading, but just start where is is placed in the sourcecode with the first reference.

What I tried:
I have a working document with a main bibliography at the end (before the appendix), created by `\printbibliography`.

options:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

---

In the appendix I added:

```
\begin{refsegment}

\printbibliography[keyword=myPapers]
\end{refsegment}
```

Which had no visible effect at all. (No bibliography created.)

- Does biblatex recognize, that the papers were already cited?
- the main bibliography was *not* in a `refsegment`-group!

---

I added a `\nocite{Martin2007a, Martin2007b, Martin2008a, etc.}` and now the list of papers is ok, however the same papers (also with the same number) appear in the main bibliography, even if they were not cited in the main document!

- how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `refsection` environment instead of `refsegment`, then you can `\nocite{*}` all bibliography entries without affection the main bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@ARTICLE{notminenotcited,
    author = {Somebody Else},
    title = {Not Mine -- Not Cited}
}

@ARTICLE{notminecited,
    author = {Somebody Else},
    title = {Not Mine -- Cited}
}

@ARTICLE{minenotcited,
    author = {Me},
    title = {Mine -- Not Cited},
    keywords = {myPapers}
}

@ARTICLE{minecited,
    author = {Me},
    title = {Mine -- Cited},
    keywords = {myPapers}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8,defernumbers, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
\cite{notminecited}, \cite{minecited}

\printbibliography

\appendix

\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=myPapers,title={My papers}, prefixnumbers={P.}, heading=bibnumbered]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

(The `filecontents*` environment is for demonstration purposes only in order to create a self-contained [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) - you can delete it and use your own bibliography file, of course.)

Please note: In this configuration, [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) creates several auxiliary files, so you'll have to run `bibtex8 <filename>.aux` and `bibtex8 <filename>1-blx.aux` - information which commands to call can be found in the log file. (`latexmk` can do all necessary compiling automatically - also with `biblatex`.)

If you're using an older version of `biblatex` (e.g. the one shipped with TeX Live 2010), you'll have to upgrade it to the latest version on CTAN, otherwise the example won't work as expected.

I didn't know how you want to handle the numbering of the entries in the bibliography - I used the `defernumbers` package option in order to reset the numbers in the list of your own papers - like this, the numbering of the main bibliography and the appendix are completely independent, both start with `[1]` (this might, however, cause some confusion).

Comment: thank you! It seems that `refsection` and `defernumbers` did the trick! With `heading=bibnumbered` I also get the corresponding chapter-heading as "appendix A".

Comment: p.s. I decided not to use `\nocite{Martin2007a, Martin2007b, etc}` with an explicit list of papers in my real document instead of `\nocite{*}`, as my bibliography file is very large (>3000 entries) and so it would produce a 5 MB `.bbl` file which should IMHO only be bad for performance and compiling time (or is this not true?).

Comment: @Martin `heading=bibnumbered` gives the bibliography the default title and also invokes `\chapter` or `\section` depending on your document class. For no heading you can use `heading=none`, with `none` defined as `\defbibheading{none}{}`. This definition is already done for you as of version 1.5.

Comment: @Audrey: thank you! I had found that myself, finally. The none-option does not work at the moment, as I still have biblatex 1.4 (and need to find out how I can update), but 'bibnumbered' does exactly what I need. (see my edits in diabonas' answer)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, since you're using bibtex8 as the backend and natbib-style citation commands, do you have the option of forgoing biblatex entirely? If so, you could load the bibunits package to achieve what you're after. Back to biblatex: I'm surprised that none of the examples in section 10.5.3 of the user guide seem to meet your needs.

Comment: I switched to biblatex less than 1 day ago and it was very painful. :-( I was struggling half a night, until it now seems to work without major errors. I tried to use `biber` as backend, but it did not work yet, so I switched to `bibtex8`. The `natbib=true`-option is to avoid all the natbib-citation-commands in my >200 pages to break - I'll try to get rid of it later.

Comment: The main problem is to exclude the references from the main bibliography, which are not cited in the document body. The problem is: there are also citations in the appendix, so if I'd define 2 refsegments, the second one would be inside the first one. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe biblatex lets you create non-nested refsegment environments, say, one for each chapter of a book, or one for the msinmatter and one for the appendix (or, more exciting still, one for each appendix). That at be what you need in order for all your \nocite elements not to show up in the main bibliography.